# In Microsoft OneNote 2013 for Android, is it possible to move a page from one folder or section to another?

Tags: notes, microsoft-onenote

In Microsoft OneNote 2013 for Android, is it possible to move a page (aka note) from one folder to another or even just from one section to another?

This seems like very rudimentary functionality, yet appears impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the functionality to move pages between different sections doesn't appear to be available. I would love it if you could move pages between sections, and even move sections between different notebooks.

As a workaround, the functionality IS available on the web version of OneNote. If you have the OneNote notebook stored in your OneDrive (which I can't see ANY reason why you wouldn't) then log into www.onenote.com and move the pages between sections using the browser.

Then, sync your notebook with your Android device again.

Comment: Thanks so much!  Hopefully Microsoft will include this essential functionality.  It's interesting (but not surprising) they have shipped a product with incomplete functionality.

Comment: As a developer, I can understand why they have shipped a product with 'incomplete functionality'. Getting the product to market sooner to gain market share is one advantage. Also, doing certain tasks on some platforms / devices might not have a suitable metaphor or way of working, or just make sense. I could see that the accidental movement of sections on devices might cause issues for some users.

Comment: I agree... when the app was brand new. But the app is mature enough now that all essential functionality should be included. I think moving a note from one folder to another is essential!  It's the one detraction that keeps me from using the product.